# i need a pop up when click a list item

Tags: python, list, kivy, kivymd

i'm building an app and i have a list with different items on them and those items have other notes that explains them but i cant seem to put the on_click or on_press or on_release function on the list to pop up the information of the list

```
<Screen>:
    name: 'team'
    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        MDToolbar:
            title: 'shock'
            pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.95}
        
        ScrollView:
            MDList:
                TwoLineListItem:
                    text: 'Shock Problem 1'
                    secondary_text: "Shock Absorbers Leaking"
                    on_release: pop up("Click!")
                TwoLineListItem:
                    text: 'Shock Problem 2'
                    secondary_text: "Uneven Tyres"
                    on_release: pop up("Click!")
                TwoLineListItem:
                    text: 'Shock Problem 3'
                    secondary_text: "Bad Vibrations"
                    on_release: pop up("Click!")
                TwoLineListItem:
                    text: 'Shock Problem 4'
                    secondary_text: "Stopping takes longer"
                    on_release: pop up("Click!")
                TwoLineListItem:
                    text: 'Shock Problem 5'
                    secondary_text: "Swerving and Veering"
                    on_release: pop up("Click!")
                TwoLineListItem:
                    text: 'Shock Problem 6'
                    secondary_text: "Knocking Noise"
                    on_release: pop up("Click!")
                TwoLineListItem:
                    text: 'Shock Problem 7'
                    secondary_text: "Bumpy Rides"
                    on_release: pop up("Click!")
        MDFlatButton:
            text: 'Back'
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.7, 'center_y': 0.1}
            on_release:
                root.manager.transition.direction = 'right' 
                root.manager.current = 'welcome'
```

i need help on what next to do so that i can get that value pop up whenever i click on the list item

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to call a method from the `TwoLineListItem`, just change:

```
on_release: pop up("Click!")
```

to:

```
on_release: app.popup("Click!")
```

And add that method to your app:

```
def popup(self, *args):
    print('popup:')
    for arg in args:
        print('\t', arg)
```

Comment: Okay I’ve added your suggestion but it prints on my run page, it doesn’t pop up

Comment: Of course not, There are only `print` statements in my code. Have a look at [Popup](https://kivy.org/doc/stable-2.0.0/api-kivy.uix.popup.html#module-kivy.uix.popup).

Comment: you've not gotten my point yet, i'm sorry but what i want is whenever i click in the list item it pops up the information which i used as ("click") above but from the correction you gave me it worked partially but it doesn't pop up on my app screen rather it prints on the run page. i want what is being printed on the run page popping up on my app screen.

Comment: I do get your point. That is why I suggested looking at [Popup](https://kivy.org/doc/stable-2.0.0/api-kivy.uix.popup.html#module-kivy.uix.popup).

Comment: i've looked at it and i'm not able to get what i want. i really need help on it, i'm so stuck right now

Comment: Here are [examples](https://kivy.org/doc/stable-2.0.0/api-kivy.uix.popup.html#examples). That is about as simple as it can get.

Comment: thats the problem i'm having. Inputting it in my code. i understand the principle of popup but getting it to pop up in my code is the major issue and thats where i need help